# T-SQL Query - how to create a new temporary "location" in a table under a location column that combines other location data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, sql-server-2016

While running a query that selects a Location, date, and visitIDs, I need to be able to select a new combined location name (eg. "LOC3+4") which includes all the rows from locations "LOC3" and "LOC4". This new dataset need to have **its own location name** so that I can group the data by Location in an SSRS report.

**Simplified Query - EDITED to add joins and subqueries-- the combined location that doesn't exist yet**.

```
SELECT subq1.Date, subq1.Location, Count(subq1.VisitID)
FROM 
    (SELECT t1.Date, t1.Location, t1.VisitID 
        FROM table t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        table t2 ON t2.VisitID = t1.VisitID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        table t3 ON t3.ClientID = t2.ClientID
        (etc)
    WHERE t1.FacID = FAC1 AND t1.Status = 'Adm') subq1 
WHERE subq1.Location = 'LOC1' AND subq1.Room NOT IN ('Room1','Room2',etc....)

UNION ALL
-- repeat for LOC2-5 

UNION ALL
(not sure how to do the combined location)
```

**Expected Results (includes combined location with expected result)**

[image: expected data]

Comment: You want "LOC3+4" in the `select` to become `LOC3-4` in the image of the results? What other sorts of combined locations might you have? "LOC1to9", "LOC129", "LOC1...9" or "LOC1-9" to represent all of the values from "LOC1" to "LOC9"? "LOC1+3+42"?

Comment: LOC3+4 is the only combined location I need (in the real world, the two locations are treated as one location for certain types of data collection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Expand on GMB's answer, I think you need one or more UNIONS in the cross apply to include both the original and the mapped locations.

```
select t.date, x.location, count(*) cnt
from mytable t
cross apply (
    select location
    union all
    select 'LOC3-4' AS location where t.location in ('LOC3', 'LOC4')
    union all
    select 'LOC2-5' AS location where t.location in ('LOC2', 'LOC3', 'LOC4', 'LOC5')
) x
group by t.date, x.location
```

A better solution may be to use a table driven mapping that associates original locations with mapped/combined locations.

```
declare @mapping table (location varchar(10), mapped_location varchar(10))
insert @mapping
values
    ('LOC3', 'LOC3-4'),('LOC4', 'LOC3-4'),
    ('LOC2', 'LOC2-5'),('LOC3', 'LOC2-5'),('LOC4', 'LOC2-5'),('LOC5', 'LOC2-5')

select t.date, x.location, count(*) cnt
from mytable t
cross apply (
    select location
    union all
    select m.mapped_location as location
    from @mapping m
    where m.location = t.location
) x
group by t.date, x.location
```

If there are no matching entries, you only count the original location. The mapping can also define multiple mapped locations for a single source location.

Both of the above generate results like:

| date | location | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-31 | LOC1 | 1 |
| 2022-10-31 | LOC2 | 2 |
| 2022-10-31 | LOC2-5 | 14 |
| 2022-10-31 | LOC3 | 3 |
| 2022-10-31 | LOC3-4 | 7 |
| 2022-10-31 | LOC4 | 4 |
| 2022-10-31 | LOC5 | 5 |

(using abbreviated test data)

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6ku1UsjN) for a demo.

Comment: Thanks so much for expanding on GMB's answer.  So, my actual non-simplified query has some joins in it and a subquery in it, and I'm sure how to place the cross apply (or whether that's even allowed -- I did a search and can't find examples.). ie. do I place it after joins or incorporate it into the existing joins somehow? I adjusted the sample query so it shows joins and more details in the WHERE clauses too to give you

Comment: You should be able to place an cross apply anywhere that you can place a join, so you could have something like `select ... from ... join ... cross apply ... join ...`. This is also true withing subqueries. The only limitation is that you have to introduce any data referenced by that cross apply (location in this case) before the cross apply that references it.

Comment: I got your second solution to work in a test query!  Problem is that the query as written won't work in a sqlview because a view doesn't work with parameters apparently -- it seems I need to create a stored procedure or function that does this.  Which would you recommend?  I haven't made either before.  I tried to make a stored procedure but I couldn't figure out how to set the first @ line -- it wants a default for @mapping table [= default], but couldn't find this information with Google search

Comment: Overall, this answered the question perfectly.  I'm going to work on making it work with a stored procedure, but I think that's a separate question/issue to work through.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional expression to assign the new location. In SQL Server, it is handy to do this in `cross apply` :

```
select t.date, x.new_location, count(*) cnt
from mytable t
cross apply ( values 
    (case when location in ('LOC3', 'LOC4') then 'LOC3-4' else location end)
) x(new_location)
group by t.date, x.new_location
```

Comment: using `values` for a single row sounds overkill, but you do you

Comment: Thanks, this gives me a starting point.  T N seems to already address some of the questions I was going to ask too, so I'm going to play around and see whether I can make it work (my actual query has a bunch of complicated joins, so not sure how to fit that in yet)